# Verification of few Riemann integration functions

Tags: real-analysis

Pick out the functions which are Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

(a) $f(x)= 1$ , if $x$ is rational     and $f(x)=0$,  if $x$ is irrational
(b)   $f(x)= 1$ , if $x∈{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ….,\alpha_n}$ is rational     and $f(x)=0$,  otherwise,    where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ….,\alpha_n$  are fixed , but arbitrarily chosen numbers in $[0,1]$
(c)  and $f(x)=0$,  if $x$ is irrational    or if $x=0$   And $f(x)=\sin(q\pi)$,  if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ , and $q$ positive and coprime integers.
(d) $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(24\pi x)$.
(e) $f(x)= \cos x$ , if $0≤x≤\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=\sin x $,  if $\frac{1}{2}<x≤1$

(a) is not true and it it a very common example.
(b) since only finitely many dis continuities so it is true.
(c) no idea
(d) no idea
(e) true. Since only one point of discontinuity.

Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ($c$), simply note that $\sin(q\pi)=0$ for all integers $q$, hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. For $(d)$, recall that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. What is the range of $\cos^{2n}(24\pi x)$ and when does it equal the maximum? This should provide you with enough information to answer the question.

Comment: then both the functions are true in c and d . am i right

Comment: That is correct @poton.

Comment: are my views correct for the other options?

Comment: Yes, your other answers are correct.